# How to declare and initialize static constant strings in classes?

Tags: c++, string, initialization, constants, declaration

I'm writing a Yatzy program for c++ class. We are supposed to print the value of different dice using std::cout. What I want to do is so save a constant string as then just that constant to print the dice out, so rather than using:

```
std::cout << "-------\n|     |\n|  *  |\n|     |\n-------\n"
```

I want to have a constant string with that value and do this:

```
std::cout << theConstantString;
```

Generic programming wins again!

```
-------
|     |
|  *  |
|     |
-------
```

The solution I have for it seems suboptimal to me. This is the relevant code:

YatzyIO.h

```
class YatzyIO
{
    private:

    // Define die constants
    static const std::string dieOnePrint;
    static const std::string dieTwoPrint;
    static const std::string dieThreePrint;
    static const std::string dieFourPrint;
    static const std::string dieFivePrint;
    static const std::string dieSixPrint;


    void dieOne();
    void dieTwo();
    void dieThree();
    void dieFour();
    void dieFive();
    void dieSix();
```

};
(there are more code than that in there, I just cut anything that wasn't relevent, which I assume I'm supposed to anyway)

Now, outside the implementation of any function in YatzyIO.cpp:

```
const std::string YatzyIO::dieOnePrint = "-------\n|     |\n|  *  |\n|     |\n-------\n";
const std::string YatzyIO::dieTwoPrint = "-------\n|  *  |\n|     |\n|  *  |\n-------\n";
const std::string YatzyIO::dieThreePrint = "-------\n| *   |\n|  *  |\n|   * |\n-------\n";
const std::string YatzyIO::dieFourPrint = "-------\n| * * |\n|     |\n| * * |\n-------\n";
const std::string YatzyIO::dieFivePrint = "-------\n| * * |\n|  *  |\n| * * |\n-------\n";
const std::string YatzyIO::dieSixPrint = "-------\n| * * |\n| * * |\n| * * |\n-------\n";
```

And finally in YatzyIO.ccp I have these functions:

```
void YatzyIO::dieOne()
{
    //output die side 1
    std::cout << dieOnePrint;
}
```

(+1 for each die, and it looks similar)

This is only lab 2 of 3 I've finished so far, the third replaces these consts with arrays. I was graded on lab 1, which contain this code as well and my teacher said (and I'm translating here since I'm swedish, so whatever is lost in translation I'm sorry!):

"It's good that you use member variable so save the different dice output. I suggest you save the different lines (that form the different output) in your member variables instead."

What does he mean? Is there a better way to do it? I can't initizalize non-integer constants in the header file. I've tried a bunch of different way, because honestly my solution seems not so optimal to me.

Comment: That doesn't really make any sense.  But perhaps the point is that you should be using an array rather than 6 individually-named member functions and member variables.

Comment: You could save on code by having one print function that takes an integer argument to let you choose what string to print but I am not really clear on what you are asking exactly

Comment: As @OliCharlesworth said, that makes no sense. But here's my question to you: Did he say member variable or class variable? Cause those aren't member variables.

Comment: You could also generate the Strings on the fly. That's much nicer in my opinion.

Comment: @Linuxios: In C++, those *are* member variables, in particular *static member* variables. The standard calls *member* anything that is defined in the context of a class, including functions, nested types, instance and static variables.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Thank you for the terminology. I'm used to calling them class and instance variables, not member and static member.

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher is probably suggesting that all different outputs are actually the combination of a small subset of lines, and that you could just maintain those lines and compose the solution as needed, rather than maintaining the whole dice image.

For example `-------\n` appears as the top and bottom borders for each and every different combination, `| * * |\n` can be used to generate the top and bottom lines of 4, 5 and 6, and also the middle element of 6. `|  *  |\n` can be the middle line for 1, 3, 5 and you will need an empty line for the top and bottom lines of 1, and for the middle lines in 2 and 4... You can store those as members and then generate the dice drawings based on those primitives.

For example, to draw a 6 you need to do:

```
std::cout << line        // -------
          << two_dots    // | * * |
          << two_dots    // | * * |
          << two_dots    // | * * |
          << line;       // -------
```

This way you only need to store the 4 primitives rather than all of the complete dice values.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought. I wasn't sure enough to write it as an answer though